# ReactJs Isotope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to develop a reactjs Isotope component. I've created the core component and been following the masonary link 
http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/01/07/react-js-with-isotope-and-flux/

I'm getting the error "Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?"

//lastet jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/54/

```
var Grid = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){

  var $container = $('#Isotope2'),
      $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });
  // get Isotope instance
  var isotope = $container.data('isotope');
  // add even classes to every other visible item, in current order
  function addEvenClasses() {
    isotope.$filteredAtoms.each( function( i, elem ) {
      $(elem)[ ( i % 2 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ) ]('even')
    });
  }

  $checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
    addEvenClasses();
  });

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
    addEvenClasses();
  });

  return null;

  },
  render: function() {
    return ( < div className = "grid" >
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
      < /div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render( < Grid name = "Isotope2" / > , document.getElementById('Isotope2'));
```

Comment: As you're using jsx, you should replace all your `class="item ..."` with `className="item..."`, otherwise it doesn't work. This is what the error message says, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

JSX is not *exactly* the same as HTML. There are some [key differences](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html).

In this case, the error message is telling you what's wrong. You need to replace `class`, which is a reserved JS keyword, with `className`:

```
render: function() {
  return ( 
    <div className="grid">
      <div className="item red"></div>
      <div className="item blue"></div>
      ...etc
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/55/ - yes you guys are right - now it won't shuffle Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Comment: Not familiar with isotope, but I'm guessing it's because you're calling `isotope.$filteredAtoms.each`, without ever defining `$filteredAtoms`.

Comment: Spend some time seeing if you can solve the problem before asking on StackOverflow - the only way to get better as a programmer is to practice debugging :)

Comment: I am at the tipping point. I can see isotope.$filteredAtoms is undefined or not populated. Not sure why - is it being invokved before the render takes place?

Comment: Ah, I took a closer look at your code; yeah, `getInitialState` is called before the components are rendered to the DOM, so isotope's selectors don't work. You'll want to put this logic in `componentDidMount`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/67/ - managed to get it working - still getting some errors though

Comment: So, shameless self-plug, but I actually wrote a React module that does exactly what you're trying to do, without Isotope. Configuration couldn't be easier: https://github.com/joshwcomeau/react-flip-move

Comment: As a general rule, React does not play nicely with other libraries that mutate the DOM. You're going to have constant issues if you let Isotope mutate the DOM that React rendered.

I realized that your demo has entry/exit animations, which my Flip Move doesn't yet handle. If you need those, I'd recommend React Shuffle

Answer (score 0):

JSX is alittle bit different than the HTML.
There are few differences that is listed in the [DOM differences in React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html).

DOM `class` attribute is replaced in React with `className`since `class` is a JavaScript reserved word.

> Since class and for are reserved words in JavaScript, the JSX elements for built-in DOM nodes should use the attribute names className and htmlFor respectively, (eg.  ). Custom elements should use class and for directly (eg.  ).